# Unclear TypeError "is not a function" with function in same JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, typeerror

**Okay, I've looked in a few different places and most of the issues I find are with JQuery. Also - this is more of a "the more eyes the better" effort than a "teach me" kind of thing...**

Anyway, I have an app I've to develop and I'm trying to use an MVC pattern. So there are 3 scripts: `ConverterModel.js`, `ConverterView.js` and `ConverterController.js`, which are loaded into the `index.html` in that order, 
that is to say:

```
 <script src="ConverterModel.js"></script>
 <script src="ConverterView.js"></script>
 <script src="ConverterController.js"></script>
```

Inside `ConverterController.js`, all I'm trying to do is call one function, `setNumberClickCallbacks()`, from **inside** the `init()` function. These are both in the same file.

I have the code below with irrelevant methods omitted:

```
"use strict";

/*globals ConverterModel, ConverterView*/

var model = new ConverterModel(),
    view = new ConverterView(),
    controller = null;

function ConverterController() {

    this.init = function () {
        view.setMenuClickCallback(this.menuButtonCallback); //This line works fine
        this.setNumberClickCallbacks(); //Apparently this is not a function
    };

    this.setNumberClickCallbacks = function () {
        //Calls multiple methods from ControllerView.js
    };

    this.menuButtonCallback = function () {
        controller.toggleMenu();
        view.toggleMenuIcon();
    };
}

controller = new ConverterController();
window.addEventListener("load", controller.init);
```

Now, I haven't worked with javascript for long, so I'm not quite used to its subtleties yet, so I think it might be something silly, but `this.setNumberClickCallbacks();` is throwing `Uncaught TypeError: this.setNumberClickCallbacks is not a function` and I **cannot** figure out why.

Like I say, I just want to know that there is more than one person looking at it and chances are, I'll look at it again tomorrow and it'll hit me, however I wanted to be proactive - so here I am.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Conner

Comment: The relationship between the object and that "method" is lost when you pass the reference to `.addEventListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer to this question works too, and although I did not use it, it made me look specifically at the relationship between the function (or "method" as I've sometimes called it in the question), `setNumberClickCallbacks` and the `ConverterController` object, much appreciation for that!

Upon checking I realised that I'd set up the script by first declaring the `var controller`  as `null`. This is then defined later, at the end of the file as a new instance of `ConverterController()`.

This then means that throughout the file, the `var controller` can be used to refer to functions from the same object.

**In short, I made the following change to the `init()` function:**

**From:**

```
view.setMenuClickCallback(this.menuButtonCallback);
this.setNumberClickCallbacks();
```

**To:**

```
view.setMenuClickCallback(controller.menuButtonCallback);
controller.setNumberClickCallbacks();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like

```
window.addEventListener("load", controller.init.bind(controller));
```

To set the context of that function.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", function(){ controller.init(); });` also works

Comment: @eithed Thank you guys for your answers - It made me look at it from a different angle and I've managed to figure out what I meant to do in the first place. To make this clear for others that may be in a similar situation, I've posted my own answer and marked it as the answer for the question as it was the one I implemented. You can have a look and give me any feedback if you'd like! Thanks again! -Conner